# left/right join

Tags: sql-server, join

I got 2 tables like this:

```
C1 
1   
1   
2   

And this is table 2

C1  C2
1   x
1   y
2   y
```

And I want that the result is:

```
C1 C2
1  x
2  null
```

I don't want to see Y but I need to see 2 for other information.

With left join it shows also null by 1 and with right join 2 wont show.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, assuming the column names match the table names:

```
SELECT C1.C1, C2.C2
  FROM C1
    LEFT JOIN C2 ON C2.C1 = C1.C1 AND C2.C2 <> 'y'
```

I'm not sure whether this is your actual requirement. You may tell us some more details about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Typo - sorry guys. I intended to use `C1` in the `FROM` clause. Edited.

Comment: Yeah, that I know. But you don't use from or join the table ?

Comment: @BBAA: I don't understand what's wrong, sorry. I do use `FROM` and `LEFT JOIN`...

Comment: @Mudu Ah did you edit it? I was certain I saw C2 by from and join :p but when you do that, you will see number 1 twice. One time with x behind it and one time with null